# Related Rates question street light pole

Tags: calculus

> A street light is mounted at the top of a $15$-ft-tall pole. A man $6$ ft tall walks away from the pole with a speed of $4$ ft/s along a straight path. How fast is the tip of his shadow moving when he is $30$ ft from the pole?

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  draw a picture.  There are similar triangles from the tip of the shadow to the man and from the tip of the shadow to the lightpost.